# How to set the selectedindex=0 for html dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html

`$('#filterByName')[0].selectedIndex` -in that i am getting selected index value.after sumit click i am setting `$('#filterByName')[0].selectedIndex=0` then this statement not setting the index 0 after click event.while debugging assigning the zero value but why in UI is not showing ?previuod selected dropdown value showing always.please tell me how to reset the dropdown value after button click in html?

```
<span id="filterByNames"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByName", new SelectList(Model.Names, "Name", "Name", Model.Name), new { onchange = "filterByName()" }) %></span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: try giving alert in click event and see if its getting fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#filterByName").val(YOUR VALUE TO SET);
```